# Django form won't display

Tags: python, html, django, forms, post

I'm working on a project and we need to add a form to add an event. It lists the name, date, time, and address. I got the form to work but when I added the base, the form doesn't show up on the web page with the base loaded. I'm thinking it has something to do with my html file. Here is my html file.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block heading %}My Events{% endblock %}
{% block content3 %}
    </h1><b><font size="5">Save Event</b></h1></font>
    <form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type ="submit" value="Add Event"/>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

views:

```
def add_event(request):
    user = request.user
    events = user.event_set.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            event = Event.objects.create(
            eventname = form.cleaned_data['eventname'],
            eventdate = form.cleaned_data['eventdate'],
            eventtime = form.cleaned_data['eventtime'],
            address = form.cleaned_data['address'],
            user = request.user
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = EventForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form
    })
    return render_to_response('add_event.html',variables)
```

base:

```
HTML (base.html)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
  <title>DelMarVa Happenings | {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="masthead">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="/site_media/Delmarva.gif" width="100px" height="80px" />
            </div>
            <h1>DelMarVa Happenings</h1>
            <br />
            <h4>A listing of events in and around Delaware, Maryland, and Virginia</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <h3>welcome, {{ user.username }}</h3>
            {% else %}
                <h3>welcome, guest</h3>
            {% endif %}
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">home<a/></li>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a href="/event/">add event</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/user/">my events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/account/">my account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/logout/">logout</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="/login/">login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/register/">register</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="ads">
            <img src="/site_media/ad.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <h2>{% block head %}{% endblock %}</h2>
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does base.html work with other templates? Could you post it here so we can look at it?

Comment: The names of your template blocks didn't match up right?

Answer (score 1):

Your `base.html` does not have a `{% block content3 %}` - rename the block name in base, or the extended template to match each other.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to leave space between form.as_p and the braces. As such, `{{ form.as_p }}`

Comment: Nothing changed when I did that

Comment: Also, the first </h1> should read <h1>. What do you mean you got the form to work? Post your views file or where you declared it.

Comment: Ah read your question wrong. So when you added the {{% extends "base.html" %} it disappeared?

Comment: Before adding the base, I got the basic form to work where you can enter the fields and add the event. But here is my views:

Comment: sorry I'm new to this website. It won't let me add the code because it goes over the limit even though it really doesn't.

Comment: and yes ono, it just disappears.

Comment: I suggest you get a tool for your browser such us FireBug. It will tell you what your errors are in the html file. It's very useful. https://getfirebug.com/

Comment: i've figured it out. Thanks though